# @Autowired Annotation in Spring give me NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to use @Autowired Annotation in Spring for  Dependency Injection 
through a simple program but i give me  following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Customer.d(Customer.java:8)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Through xml configuration it give me correct result.

My xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/> 
  <bean id="person" class="Person">
    <property name="name" value="khan"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="cust" class="Customer"></bean>
</beans>
```

Customer Class

```
public class Customer {
@Autowired  
private Person p;
 public void display(){
     System.out.println(p.getName());
 }
}
```

Person Class

```
public class Person {

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;

}
```

Main Class

```
public class Main {
    public static void   main(String[] a) {

        Resource r=new ClassPathResource("SpringXml.xml");
        BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(r);
        Customer c=(Customer)factory.getBean("cust");
        c.display();
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of just mentioning "Customer" or "Person", change it to class = "complete-package-path.Customer" if above classes are not in default package

Comment: thank you the above classes are in default package

Comment: try to use ApplicationContext while creating customer object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringXml.xml");
    Customer c = (Customer) context.getBean("cust");
    c.display();
}
```

Comment: The difference between BeanFactory and ApplicationContext is described in [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#context-introduction-ctx-vs-beanfactory)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<bean id="person" class="com.yourpackage.Person">
  <property name="name" value="khan"/>
</bean>
<bean id="cust" class="com.yourpackage.Customer">
   <property name="p" ref="person"/>
</bean>
```

dont forget to add your fullpath class package